# Instagram comic about a boy whose brother disappears then reappears with a shadow monster inside him

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, art

Some years ago I followed an artist on instagram that had drew a comic about a boy whose young brother "disappears" while playing hide and seek in a forest. He then reappears but has a kind of dark shadow monster inside him and ends up killing his mom and stuff.
I've been trying to find it for some days but can't find it, at the time I think that was the only story that the artists was posting, I don't remember the name or anything, just that it was drawn in black and white with red blood I think.